# Vue3 + Splide не работает AutoScroll

Tags: vue.js, vue3

Делаю карусель с автоскроллом, приглянулся Splide с модулем AutoScroll под задачу, но модуль упорно не хочет работать.

```
        <Splide 
          :options="{ 
            type: 'loop', 
            drag: 'free', 
            autoWidth: true, 
            gap: '4px', 
            arrows: false, 
            pagination: false,
            extensions: { AutoScroll },
            autoScroll: {
              speed: 1,
              pauseOnHover: true,
            },
          }" 
        aria-label="My Favorite Images">
          <SplideSlide>
            <img src="@/assets/images/index/slide1.png" alt="Sample 1">
          </SplideSlide>
          <SplideSlide>
            <img src="@/assets/images/index/slide1.png" alt="Sample 1">
          </SplideSlide>
          <SplideSlide>
            <img src="@/assets/images/index/slide1.png" alt="Sample 1">
          </SplideSlide>
          <SplideSlide>
            <img src="@/assets/images/index/slide1.png" alt="Sample 1">
          </SplideSlide>
          <SplideSlide>
            <img src="@/assets/images/index/slide1.png" alt="Sample 1">
          </SplideSlide>
        </Splide>
```

```
<script>
import { Splide, SplideSlide } from '@splidejs/vue-splide';
import { AutoScroll } from '@splidejs/splide-extension-auto-scroll';
import '@splidejs/vue-splide/css/core';
export default {
  components: {
    Splide,
    SplideSlide,
    AutoScroll
  },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Нужно extensions отдавать как отдельный пропс

```
import {AutoScroll} from "@splidejs/splide-extension-auto-scroll";
...
const extensions = {AutoScroll};
...
<Splide :extensions="extensions" :options="options">
```